# Android Studio undo (Ctrl-Z) / redo (Ctrl-Y) not working

Tags: android, android-studio, undo-redo

I've just moved from Eclipse to Android Studio and am finding really weird behaviour when I try to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to undo/redo code changes.

It hard to describe what happens exactly, but the end result is that I usually end up just losing my code and having to type it back in from memory...

The 'undo'  and 'redo' buttons in the IDE do seem to work fine, so maybe something is wrong with my shortcut keys (which would be surprising as I should just have a standard installation / setup).

Can anyone advise what to do, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> will work in the expected manner.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to configure intelliJ redo action for CTRL+Y instead of CTRL+Shift+Z](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244475/how-to-configure-intellij-redo-action-for-ctrly-instead-of-ctrlshiftz)

Comment: Why you didn't researched 1 minute more that was the time to post an answer on your own question?....

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me that Android Studio is similar (or same as?) intelliJ. I'm sure I'm not the only one who wasn't aware of the similarity, so I'm sure other people will have the same question as I did and not know about intelliJ.

Comment: @ban-geoengineering the description of the android-studio tag states "Android Studio is an official IDE targeted at Android development, based on IntelliJ IDEA from JetBrains".

Comment: What I said in my previous message is still correct.

Comment: ...i.e., I wasn't aware of that and nor, I suspect, will some others be.

Comment: @ban-geoengineering I have been hit by this myself. Most programs use Ctrl-Y as an easy shortcut to Redo, but some _idiots who think they know better than everyone else_ make Ctrl-Y delete lines _([an outdated shortcut from the 1980s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Y) irrelevant in the 21st century)_ **If you tried to redo what you just undid and found yourself deleting lines and panicking, you can minimize your loss by undoing the "delete line" action. But unfortunately, you will have to manually "redo" from memory what you undid.** And be sure to remap that damn keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @ADTC yes! I am still trying to figure out how Ctrl+Y could mean Delete..

Comment: @ACV one of JetBrains' annoying idiosyncrasies (which there are several of). JetBrains loves being the sardines that go against current industry standards. Google never should have based Android Studio on IntelliJ.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25244476), I have worked it out...

1. Go into `Settings` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)
2. Type `Redo` in the search box.
3. Double-click on the `Redo` result
4. Select `Add Keyboard Shortcut`
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>
6. Click `OK`
7. Click `OK`

Comment: My answer is better as it is quicker. Plus it is a valid because it's correct. If you don't like the question, then you should just downvote the question.

Answer (score 13):

To undo an action, do one of the following:

- On the menu bar, choose **Edit** -> **Undo**.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

To redo an action, do one of the following:

- On the menu bar, choose **Edit** -> **Redo**.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> deletes line by default in Android.
If you want to change this behaviour, go to Keymap under Settings and set your desired shortcut for Redo action

By the way, the same question: [how to configure intelliJ/Android Studio redo action for CTRL+Y instead of CTRL+Shift+Z](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25244475/5247331)

Comment: why downvote? I thought the author checked for duplications

Answer (score 7):

You can try this one. It is simple and default:
(<kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>)
This is for undo. 
Just press (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>) for **redo**. 
 (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd>) it has individual task. So it would be better if you don't bother this one.
1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> -> Undo
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>  <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> -> ***Redo***
3. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> -> Delete line

*Happy Coding*

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> works fine and undo the work but <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> is a bit messy combo.
Unlike most software <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> here doesn't mean redo but its infact a shortcut to delete the entire line, hence you loose your code.
So if you wanna REDO use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>(as already told above) or change keymapping.